# How to set a variable in laravel controller and use the value in exporting to excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

In my controller, I need to concatenate a string and a variable. After I concatenate it, i set it to variable **$datenow**. When i export to excel, I want to make the value of **cell A2** to **$datenow**. But then i keep getting an error of *Undefined variable: datenow*. Here's my code:

```
public function userSummary()
{
    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $datenow = 'As of'.' '.$mytime;
    Excel::create('Empoyee Summary', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) {

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'VCY Group of Companies');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $datenow);

        });

    })->export('xls');      
}
```

How to put the value of cell **A2** to **$datenow**?

Comment: replace this line --> Excel::create('Empoyee Summary', function($excel) use($datenow)

Comment: @Vipul it still says that Undefined Variable: datenow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function userSummary()
{
    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $datenow = 'As of'.' '.$mytime;
    Excel::create('Empoyee Summary', function($excel) use ($datenow) {

        $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use($datenow) {

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'VCY Group of Companies');
            $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $datenow);

        });

    })->export('xls');      
}
```

Comment: It still an error saying Undefined Variable: datenow

Comment: It worked! But what if i have other variables? Like I'll use not only $datenow. What if I have another variable like $name, should it be use($datenow, $name)?

Comment: @gwapo yes. You use it that way